Pagination on 1cr+ data in postgresql
I have a table with 1cr data. I want to show the data on UI with pagination. I have created the query with limit offset which is working fine but I am facing problem in getting number of records. Required data with limit offset with taking less than .5 sec but count(*) is taking more than 1 sec. What can be replacement for count(*) or how pagination can be performed in such case.
Query :
select count(*) 
from tablename 
where col1 = 'value' and col2 = 'value';

Index is on col1 and col2.
I tried for reltuples but it is not allowing me to apply where clause on table.
Query :
select count(*) 
from tablename 
where col1 = 'value' and col2 = 'value';

Index is on col1 and col2. Index is hitting but still taking more than 1 sec. These is no dead tuple as well.

Could you explain what 1cr data is? And could you also share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, and the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your query? And of course the query itself.
